# django field validator based on other field in same model

Tags: python, django

I have this model

```
class Env(models.Model):    
    functional_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()    
    current_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now i want `functional_count` to always be less than `current_count`.
So during create,

```
def form_valid(self, form):    
    form.instance.current_count = 0
```

This is because i want `current_count` during initialization.Then my python code never allows `current_count` to go above `functional_count`.

The problem comes in Update.

```
class EnvUpdate(UpdateView):  
    model = Capacity.models.Envapps  
    fields = ['functional_count']  
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

So do i include a validator? If yes, where and how?
Or other option is to verify in `get_success_url()`.
Any other solution?

Comment: Django's forms and models validation are fully documented. Why don't you start from here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your updates come through a form (as suggested by the use of `form_valid()`, perhaps you can use the form `clean()` method, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). This allows you to perform checks for fields that depend on each other. The documentation also has an example which should get you further.

**Update**

From your comments, I understand that you tried to use `clean()` inside `EnvUpdate`, which inherits from the class-based `UpdateView` view. All the mixins provided through `UpdateView` do apparently not provide a `clean()` method, so you can't override it.

I am actually referring to the `clean()` in a form class (as follows from the link). So, it looks like you'd need to create your own ModelForm class, something like:

```
class EnvappsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Capacity.models.Envapps
        fields = ['functional_count']

    def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
       if cleaned_data['functional_count'] >= form.instance.current_count:
           raise ValidationError('too large')
       return cleaned_data
```

and then in your view:

```
class EnvUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Capacity.models.Envapps  
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    form_class = EnvappsForm
```

Note: this is completely untested! I don't know if the comparison in the `clean()` works (i.e., if form.instance.current_count can be found), and wheter `EnvUpdate` will override the form_class (it shouldn't, but I've never tried). It just *might* be even possible that you can remove the `meta` subclass, and provide the `model` and `fields` from `EnvUpdate`, as you do yourself above. That's just something you can easily try out.

Comment: And what was the result (or resulting problem)?

Comment: I had tried the method explained in the link. But it just didn't seem to go inside the clean() function  
class EnvappsUpdate(UpdateView):  
        model = Capacity.model...
        fields = [...,'f_count',...]
        def clean(self):
                cleaned_data = super(EnvappsUpdate,self).clean()
                f_count = cleaned_data.get("f_count")
                c_count = cleand_data.get("c_count")
                print "inside clean"
                if(f_count<c_count):
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Error. f_count < c_count")
                return cleaned_data

Comment: Not sure how to format the above code properly in the comment box. Might be uneasy to make sense of it

Comment: You can't really format comments, other than using backticks. Just edit and update/expand your question instead, using code blocks; much better in general.

Answer (score 0):

If `functional_count` should always be less than `current_count` you should check it in the `clean()` method on the model and not some random `ModelForm`.  The model `clean()` will be called during normal `ModelForm` validation.